# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2A' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT M.AcType,
       A.AcTypeDesc,
       M.IntCrRate,
       Datediff(day, C.Today, D.MaturityDate)   AS DurationDay,
       Datediff(month, C.Today, D.MaturityDate) AS DurationMonth,
       Datediff(year, C.Today, D.MaturityDate)  AS DurationYear,
       'Total Deposit'=Sum(M.Balance)
FROM   Master M(nolock),
       AcTypeTable A(nolock),
       DealTable D(nolock),
       ControlTable C(nolock)
WHERE  M.AcType = A.AcType
       AND M.MainCode = D.MainCode
       AND M.AcOpenDate = D.DealOpenDate
       AND M.Balance > 0
       AND M.CyCode = '01'
GROUP  BY M.AcType,
          M.IntCrRate,
          A.AcTypeDesc,
          D.MaturityDate,
          C.Today
UNION ALL
SELECT Count(M.AcType),
       'Total',
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       Sum(M.Balance)
FROM   Master M(nolock),
       AcTypeTable A(nolock),
       DealTable D(nolock)
WHERE  M.AcType = A.AcType
       AND M.MainCode = D.MainCode
       AND M.AcOpenDate = D.DealOpenDate
       AND M.Balance > 0
       AND M.CyCode = '01'
```

> error msg :Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when
>   converting the varchar value '2A' to data type int. both the queries
>   run if run individually but when run together it doesnt

Comment: What is the datatype of first two columns `M.AcType1` and `A.AcTypeDesc` in first query

Comment: yes becuase on one you are using count function and on other not so one return interger

Comment: Please check my answer if it helps . If you have question let me know I am happy to help

Comment: can you please mark my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
               -- actype you are not using count but after union all u r using count that y you have error both table should have same columns and types
               SELECT M.AcType,
               A.AcTypeDesc,
               M.IntCrRate,
               Datediff(day, C.Today, D.MaturityDate)   AS DurationDay,
               Datediff(month, C.Today, D.MaturityDate) AS DurationMonth,
               Datediff(year, C.Today, D.MaturityDate)  AS DurationYear,
               'Total Deposit'=Sum(M.Balance)
        FROM   Master M(nolock),
               AcTypeTable A(nolock),
               DealTable D(nolock),
               ControlTable C(nolock)
        WHERE  M.AcType = A.AcType
               AND M.MainCode = D.MainCode
               AND M.AcOpenDate = D.DealOpenDate
               AND M.Balance > 0
               AND M.CyCode = '01'
        GROUP  BY M.AcType,
                  M.IntCrRate,
                  A.AcTypeDesc,
                  D.MaturityDate,
                  C.Today
        UNION ALL
        --  here count -- if its varchar then it will retun error 
        SELECT Count(M.AcType),
               'Total',
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               Sum(M.Balance)
        FROM   Master M(nolock),
               AcTypeTable A(nolock),
               DealTable D(nolock)
        WHERE  M.AcType = A.AcType
               AND M.MainCode = D.MainCode
               AND M.AcOpenDate = D.DealOpenDate
               AND M.Balance > 0
               AND M.CyCode = '01'

So to fix it please  remove count or add count(Actype on the top of query). if this type is varchar then you cannot use count
```

Comment: So either use count on both or remove . Please try if my answer helps .